# Facing bundle identifier issues with Google Cloud Platform setup not working with Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-places-api, google-maps-api-2, bundle-identifier

has any faced bundle identifier issues with Google Cloud Platform setup and Flutter app? I cant seem to figure out whats wrong and I keep getting errors from flutter:

```
flutter: errorMessage: This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 2001:8c8:1231:7a94:vc83:a41:f07e:db66, with empty referer.
```

i have rechecked several times for spelling and typos but no luck whatsoever! :
[image: screenshots]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like using the server key solved the issue [here](https://github.com/seatgeek/android-PlacesAutocompleteTextView/issues/10).